# Adding Google+ next to ASP.NET Hyperlink

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an asp.net web form hyperlink control declared in a user control as follows:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="lnk" CssClass="title" Text='<%# Eval("PostTitle") %>'
                  NavigateUrl='<%# "~/DisplayPost.aspx?ID=" + Eval("ID") %>'/>
```

I want to add a Google + Button next to this and pass the NavigateURL dynamically to the Google+ button. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

See the [Google+ button page](http://www.google.com/webmasters/+1/button/#customize-snippet) to do this.  An example for you would be as follows:

```
<!-- Place this tag where you want the +1 button to render -->
<g:plusone annotation="inline" href="<%# "~/DisplayPost.aspx?ID=" + Eval("ID") %>"></g:plusone>

<!-- Place this render call where appropriate -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>
```

There is also the option of putting a plus 1 button directly on the page that your link goes to.